# Problem building with MSBuild on Team Build

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I have recently upgraded from TFS2005 to TFS2010 (and sub-sequently the team build server).

I used to be able to get a team build on one of my solutions to work pretty easily, (see structure below)

```
Solution
|_Web Site
|    |_Bin
|    |_Other Files
|_Project 1
|_Project 2
|_Project (n)
```

Now, i can no longer get a build working correctly as it doesnt appear to build all my projects any longer (i've had to create a new build definition).  Either that, or its not building the projects in such an order that when it hits project X, that a project it depends on (Project A), has not yet been built, and as such fails.

I'm just basically trying to build a web site (not web application project), with some Dependant / linked projects.  Why must it be so hard!

Everything builds fine in the IDE.  If i even open the solution copied to the build server under the 'Sources' directory, i am able to build it fine in the IDE on that server.  No such luck with MSBuild though.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

See [Can we build a website using MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808408/can-we-build-a-website-using-msbuild).

Or convert to a web app project.

Comment: I already read / tried  the first link.  And i originally moved away from having a web application because of the amount of tfs merge issues we were having due to the number of files in the web app.

I had it working with TFS2005, it just doesnt seem to want to work with 2010, which doesnt seem to make much sense.